# How to dynamic task mapping multiple parameters as pair, not cross product using taskflow api?

Tags: airflow, airflow-taskflow

I would like to have parameter unpack in pair, set (if there is more than 2), not cross product.

```
@task
def add(x: int, y: int):
    return x + y


added_values = add.expand(x=[4, 8], y=[40, 80])
# I need
# add(x=4, y=40)
# add(x=8, y=80)

# I dont need
# add(x=4, y=80)
# add(x=8, y=40)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead take a single parameter, and pass x and y zipped together:

```
    @task
    def add(xy):
        return xy

    added_values = add.expand(xy=list(zip([4, 8], [40, 80])))
```

This would also work for 3+ parameters, for example:

```
added_values = add.expand(xy=list(zip([4, 8], [40, 80], [400, 800])))
```

Taskflow also supports [zipping the output of tasks](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html#combining-upstream-data-aka-zipping) to achieve this without hardcoding.